# SHA-256 password generator

Tags: javascript, python, sha256

i saw a javascript implementation of sha-256.
i waana ask if it is safe (pros/cons wathever) to use sha-256 (using javascript implementation or maybe python standard modules) alogrithm as a password generator:

i remember one password, put it in followed(etc) by the website address and use the generated text as the password for that website.
repeat process every time i need password
same for other websites

Comment: SHA is a hash algorithm. How is that a password generator?

Comment: He is talking about SHA with a secret prefix input, as a keyed hash function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are describing the approach used by [SuperGenPass](http://supergenpass.com/):

Take a master password (same for every site), concatenate it with the site's domain name, and then hash the thing.

Yes, SHA-256 would be secure for that, likely more secure than when SuperGenPass uses. However, you will end up with very long passwords, too long for many sites to accept, and also not guaranteed to contain numbers and letters and special characters at the same time, which some sites require.

Also, the general problem remains that if somehow (not by breaking the algorithm, but by other means) your master password does get leaked, all your passwords are belong to us.

Completely random passwords are most secure (if we ignore the problem of storing them securely somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

SHA-256 generates *very* long strings. You're better off using `random.choice()` with a string a fixed number of times.

Comment: But then he needs to write down the generated random password for every site.

Comment: @Thilo: It's a lot easier to write down a 10-character password than a 64-character password.

Comment: He does not need to write down the SHA-1 output for every site, he just has to remember the master password for all sites. Of course, he could use a password-protected file to store all the random passwords to get the same effect (unless you loses the file).

Comment: @Thilo: I see nothing about him writing a password *manager*, just a password generator.

Comment: Exactly. The password generator he describes does not need a password manager. Using random passwords requires a password manager (but is more secure, at least as long as the manager is secure).